# [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Cannot open file C:\users\aleer\locals\locals~1\temp\6uu0004.tmp?

Tags: windows-7, odbc, foxpro, squirrel-sql

Okay I checked this out and `C:\users\aleer\locals\locals~1\temp\6uu0004.tmp` is actually point to `C:\Users\aleer\Local Settings\temp` where the `6uu0004.tmp` file does not even exist.

I guess it's possible that this file is being created and then it disappears once I get to the command prompt.

I'm not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the directory the temp file was being created in wasn't owned by my user.  Changed the owner of the directory and now it works.